# Get Mac address windows mobile device from desktop by activesync

Tags: windows-mobile, activesync, opennetcf

I think I search entire internet bu i cant find any solution for this. I can handle the connection by RAPI (OPENNETCF Remote Apı) I can copy files and start a process but i cant get the mac address by rapi or anything else.

Comment: Seems like that question has been asked a few times before about `Windows Mobile` devices, but there has never been a good answer.

Comment: I just find my way i find mac address windows ce client and wrote it on registry after this trick i read it from there by accessing registry from windows

Answer (score 0):

I just find my way i find mac address windows ce client and wrote it on registry after this trick i read it from there by accessing registry from windows